# how to run groups Active directory cmd command using java

Tags: java, user-interface, runtime

dsmod group "cn=pc3,cn=users,dc=jan,dc=com" -addmbr "cn=bob,cn=users,dc=jan,dc=com"

how to run this command in java Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
please help me
thanks alot in advance

Comment: I'd suggest you use ProcessBuilder instead.

Comment: please post a code how to use it thanks.

Comment: How to use ProcessBuilder should be easy to figure out from the docs or from searching existing questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @aioobe i know how to use ProcessBuilder but i can't use this command on processbuilder.

Comment: Why can't you do that?

Comment: @aioobe it has double quotations in the middle i can't handle it.

Comment: Did you tried making the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` call? What problems did you run into when doing that?

Answer (score 0):

yes i can do the following.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dsmod group \"cn=pc3,cn=users,dc=jan,dc=com\" -addmbr \"cn=bob,cn=users,dc=jan,dc=com"");
```